# How to detect the state of the screen rotation?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

I am writing an implementation of [`orientationchangeend`](https://github.com/gajus/orientationchangeend) event.

To detect the end of [`orientationchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/orientationchange), I am tracking the state of `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` after the `orientationchange` event has been fired. If these values do to not change for `X` number of iterations (using `setInterval`), I fire the `orientationchangeend`.

Is there another variable I could be tracking instead of `window.innerWidth`/`window.innerHeight` that is more definitive? Is the rotation progress exposed anywhere in the API? (e.g. CSS transformation that rotates the screen; assuming there is one).

Comment: This will become possible with the introduction of Screen Orientation API, http://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation/, which is not available in iOS 8 http://caniuse.com/#feat=screen-orientation.

Comment: It is not available in iOS 9 as well.